# search and replace some portion of text in a file using perl

Tags: file, perl, replace

I have written a perl script to replace the text in a file with some other text, keeping some portion of search text as it is.
But, my script is not working as expected, I have seen similar questions in Stackoverflow and followed the suggestions, still the script is not giving the expected output.
please see the below text (highlighted) which I expect to replace in the file and the corresponding script written

[image]
[image]

In the file, I want to replace the decimal values with '150'.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

```perl
#!usr/bin/perl    
  2 
  3 use strict;
  4     use warnings;
  5      
  6     my $filename = 'input_file.txt';
  7      
  8     my $data = read_file($filename);
  9      $data =~ s/(g_clk.*-multiply_by\s\+)\d\+/$1 150/ge;
 10     print "$data\n";
 11     write_file($filename, $data);
 12     exit;
 13      
 14     sub read_file {
 15         my ($filename) = @_;
 16      
 17         open my $in, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename or die "Could not open '$filename' for reading $!";
 18         local $/ = undef;
 19         my $all = <$in>;
 20         close $in;
 21      
 22         return $all;
 23     }
 24      
 25     sub write_file {
 26         my ($filename, $content) = @_;
 27      
 28         open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename or die "Could not open '$filename' for writing $!";;
 29         print $out $content;
 30         close $out;
 31      
 32         return;
 33     }
```

Comment: It is a lot better to supply copy-pastable text samples of code and input/output. As a courtesy to people trying to help you, saving them time from having to type out the things you want fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As near as I can tell, you have one fatal error in your regex.

```
$data =~ s/(g_clk.*-multiply_by\s\+)\d\+/$1 150/ge;
#                                ^^   ^^
```

You have escaped the plus sign `+`, which makes it lose its special meaning as a quantifier, and now it just means to "match a literal plus sign".

If you remove the backslash before plus, it should work.

However, that is not the only mistake you make.

- You use the `/g` global modifier, even though you really do not want to match more than once per line.
- You use the `/e` eval modifier, even though you really do not want to evaluate the replacement part as Perl code.

As for questionable design choices:

- You slurp the file into a single variable instead of reading line-by-line, even though you really only want to match once per line (this is probably why you are using the `/g` global modifier)
- You add an extra newline in your `print "$data\n";` line.
- You end your program with `exit`, even though the program will naturally exit at the end of executable code.
- If you still do want to slurp your file, it is better to use the already invented module [`File::Slurp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp) than to re-invent the wheel.

Also, this is can be solved with "so called" a one-liner. This is a core function of Perl, to in-place edit a file. You can get away with something as simple as this:

```
perl -pe's/g_clk.*-multiply_by \K\d+/150/' input.txt > output.txt
```

This will write to a new file, using the shell to redirect output. You can also edit a file in place using the `-i` switch:

```
perl -pi.bak -e's/g_clk.*-multiply_by \K\d+/150/' input.txt
```

This will save the original file with a `.bak` extension. Be careful though, as running the command twice will still overwrite your original file. The best option is to save a permanent backup before attempting to in-place edit.

This style of program is the short version of this (excluding the in-place edit)

```
while (<>) {
    s/g_clk.*-multiply_by \K\d+/150/;
    print;
}
```

Comment: Thanks TLP for your detailed explanation of my errors.. all the comments are very helpful..!!

Comment: @Sonali You know that you can upvote an answer, and mark it as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change the regexpr by this:

```
$data =~ s/(-multiply_by\s+)\d+/$1 150/g;
```

It matches "`-multiply_by`" and spaces (`\s+`) followed by 1 or more digits (`\d+`). Use the parenthesis to memorize the text (in `$1`). That is useful at the second part (the replacement section)

**UPDATE 1**: to replace a concrete section (delimited by line numbers), is better to read the file line by line and then use the $. special variable to apply the regexpr when needed. Example:

```
open my $in, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename_in or die $!;
open my $out, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename_out or die $!;

while( my $data = <$in> ) {
    if( $. >= 4 && $. <= 12) {
        # Replace only if line number ($.) is between 4 and 12
        $data =~ s/(-multiply_by\s+)\d+/$1 150/g;
    }
    # Print at output the handled line
    print $out $data;
}

close $in;
close $out;
```

**UPDATE 2**: to replace a concrete section (delimited by other value of the same line), search your condition like this:

```
open my $in, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename_in or die $!;
open my $out, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename_out or die $!;

while( my $data = <$in> ) {
    if( $data =~ /-name glck / ) {
        # Replace only if line has "-name glck" text
        $data =~ s/(-multiply_by\s+)\d+/$1 150/g;
    }
    # Print at output the handled line
    print $out $data;
}

close $in;
close $out;
```

Comment: Thanks alot Miguel for your time..!!!, But, I want to replace the lines which have 'glck' (line number in the file 4 to 12) only, the script you shared will replace all the lines with 150. I wonder, why the script is not working if I include 'gclk.*' in the replace command.

Comment: Thanks Miguel for the solutions in different view..!!!

Answer (score 1):

Following code demonstrates one of many approaches

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $re  = qr/^create_gene_clk .*? g_clk .*? -multiply_by \K\d+/;
my $mul = 150;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    s/$re/$mul/;
    say;
}

__DATA__
create_gene_clk -name dft_clk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 104 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name dft_clk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 204 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name dft_clk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 324 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]

create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 14 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/D)] -multiply_by 104 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/E)] -multiply_by 114 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/R)] -multiply_by 001 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/T)] -multiply_by 154 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/Y)] -multiply_by 182 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/U)] -multiply_by 194 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 004 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 104 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]

create_gene_clk -name bgclk -source [get_pins (5201/U)] -multiply_by 104 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name bgclk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 104 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name bgclk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 104 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
```

Output

```
create_gene_clk -name dft_clk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 104 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name dft_clk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 204 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name dft_clk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 324 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]

create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 150 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/D)] -multiply_by 150 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/E)] -multiply_by 150 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/R)] -multiply_by 150 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/T)] -multiply_by 150 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/Y)] -multiply_by 150 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/U)] -multiply_by 150 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 150 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name g_clk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 150 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]

create_gene_clk -name bgclk -source [get_pins (5201/U)] -multiply_by 104 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name bgclk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 104 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
create_gene_clk -name bgclk -source [get_pins (5201/C)] -multiply_by 104 -add -master_clk [get_clk {fin}] [get_p {pll/clk/out}]
```